# IDEA 14.x Mac OSX. JBoss AS 7 "Server is not connected. Deploy is not available"

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, jboss7.x

I have looked at all the other answers posted.  Have spent several fruitless hours trying to determine why my JBoss AS 7 deploy from IDEA 14.x has stopped working.  It has been working fine for the last 9 months, and now fails.

On executing the deploy Jboss Run Configuration, the ear file I'm using fails to deploy. The Jboss instance (standalone) **is** started successfully, if I click the artefact & click deploy - it displays

```
"Server is not connected. Deploy is not available"
```

I checked all the usual possibilities.

1. I made sure JDK/Java versions tally between IDE & JBoss runtime.
2. I can deploy the same artefact to Glassfish in the IDE.
3. I can deploy the same artefact to JBoss from the admin console.
4. I checked the JBoss ports 8080, 9990 etc. - they're all fine.
5. I checked that any recent Mac OS security updates mentioned Java - no nothing.

Still stumped...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution was:

`Mac OSX 'System Preferences' -> Sharing -> Computer Name`

This was blank.  Re-adding the 'Computer Name' fixed this.

Effectively my laptop had no hostname, defaulted to 'localhost', and this was tripping up the connection from IDEA to JBoss.

Just posting this in case it can save others from wasting their time.